# using knock-out for width of kendo-ui input wrraper

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, kendo-ui, width

I work in durandal project (where javascript and html written in separated pages).
I have kendo-combo, and I give it width by declare the wrraper-input width.
It works well. But when I change it to be binded- it does not work.
here is my code (which is not working):

**html:**

```
<input id="kendoCombo" data-bind=" value:'444', style:{width:width},
        kendoDropDownList: { dataSource: data,
        dataValueField:itemValue,
        dataTextField: itemText,
        value:selectedId,
        template: template,
        change:onChange}" />
```

**javascript:**

```
width:ko.observable('100px')
```

When my width has not been binded yet, it works well. Here is my previous html code:

```
<input style="width:100 
      id=" kendoCombo " 
      data-bind=" value: '444',
      kendoDropDownList: { dataSource: data,      
                           dataValueField:itemValue,
                           dataTextField: itemText,
                           value:selectedId, 
                           template: template,
                           change:onChange} " />
```

Comment: Which KO version are you using? Why do you want to bind the width? Do you only want to initialize your dropdown width once or do you want to update it later also e.g with `width('50px')`

Comment: ebram tharwat, Your example not include kendo-ui combo. Binding width of regular input- I know I to do it, too.

Comment: nemesv- I use version 2.3.0, I want to bind the width becouse I want to change it later.

Comment: @user3127364 the width of the `kendoDropDownList` is only set **once** during the intialization, so you cannot set it later even if you don't use knockout. So you probably need to change the source of the KendoUi for this to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Kendo only set the `width` of the `DropDownList` once when it is initialized, so when Knockout updates the `width` in the style binding it has no effect on the `DropDownList`.

However you can set `width` on the `wrapper` property (requires: Q1 2013 (version 2013.1.319) or newer) of the `kendoDropDownList` and you can put this logic into a custom bindingHandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.kendoDropDownListWidth = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var dropdownlist = $(element).data("kendoDropDownList");
        dropdownlist.wrapper[0].style["width"] = 
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
<input id="kendoCombo" data-bind=" value:'444', 
        kendoDropDownListWidth: width,
        kendoDropDownList: { dataSource: data,
        dataValueField:itemValue,
        dataTextField: itemText,
        value:selectedId,
        template: template,
        change:onChange}" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7BQ/).

Comment: I tried it and it works well. Thank you. Now I have a problem: I give to html-input-element width '206px'. To the kendoDropDownListWidth I give '206px' (throus the bindingHandler, too), but it not seem same. So I give throus the bindinghandler width '220px', and know it look like the input. My be there is another property I can use (something else, not kendoDropDownList)?